# Intellij run application without programe arguments or vm options

Tags: java, intellij-idea, command-line-arguments

When I run an application with Intellij, it always helps me to add a lot of arguments or VM options, like:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin/java 
-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify 
-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=45123 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost 
-Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain 
-Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true 
-javaagent:some/idea_rt.jar=40157:/home/vincent/software/intellij/bin 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
Application
```

Is there any way to let it run "clean"?

Answer (score 2):

Options added by IntelliJ IDEA would depend on the Run/Debug configuration you are using. Certain types of Run/Debug configurations add the required options automatically (like for starting Tomcat and Spring apps).

Also, IntelliJ IDEA uses the special launcher which provides additional features like thread dumps and graceful shutdown, plus the command line shortening to overcome certain OS command line limits.

If you want to get rid of all the options, use the plain Java Application Run/Debug configuration (or JAR Application). You can also disable the launcher agent by adding `idea.no.launcher=true` in Help | Edit Custom Properties and restarting IntelliJ IDEA.

Another way is to start your app externally, outside of IntelliJ IDEA and use Remote debug configuration to connect and debug it.